# What is window in SQL?

Tags: sql, window-functions

I understand that window functions work with set of rows called window and in contrast to aggregate functions does not change the size of the sample. But what is window? As I understand, it is a set of rows which are passed to a function.

Imagine we have a simple query:

```
SELECT age, SUM(salary) as sum FROM workers GROUP BY age
```

Can we state that grouped rows having the same age are also a window? Because we group workers and for each group we count a sum of their salaries.Сan we say that aggregate function also works with window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it would not be correct.  A *window* is more general than aggregation.  I think this will be clear if you look at the definition of the window frame:

```
over (partition by . . . 
      order by . . .
      range/rows . . . 
     )
```

Of course, these are not all needed, but they are part of the definition of a given window.

The `PARTITION BY` *is* equivalent to the `GROUP BY` keys, specifying that a given window only has rows with the same key values.  So, it would be quite consistent to say that "`group by` processes *partitions*, returning one row per partition".

Note a key point here:  `GROUP BY` also affects the number of rows in the result set, by returning only one row per partition.  Window functions have no such effect on the result set, returning a "summarized" value per row.

In addition, a window is broader than just the `PARTITION BY` and can represent a set of rows or values relative to the current row.  That is where `ORDER BY` and `RANGE`/`ROW` come in.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, a window function or analytic function is a function which uses values from one or multiple rows to return a value for each row. ... Window functions have an OVER clause; any function without an OVER clause is not a window function, but rather an aggregate or single-row (scalar) function.

A window function performs a calculation across a set of table rows that are somehow related to the current row.

Answer (score 1):

Window functions operate on a set of rows and return a single aggregated value for each row. The term Window describes the set of rows in the database on which the function will operate. We define the Window (set of rows on which functions operates) using an OVER() clause.